# How to plot a stacked 3D barplot in python matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, 3d, bar-chart

I got a problem with producing a stacked 3D plot.
I have three columns two are from the  result = np.array(result) I want to stack add the weights array to each of the values in results in sequential order and stack them.
I tried to follow the instructions as provided in this link: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35347091/python-3d-stacked-bar-char-plot][1] but the output is always faulty. The following shows the code and traceback

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm

result = [[0.234, 0.309, 0.105, 0.367, 0.621],
          [0.126, 0.286, 0.220, 0.367, 0.066]]
weight = [0.47, 0.21, 0.16, 0.11, 0.05]

weight = np.array(weight)
result = np.array(result)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10), dpi=150)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
xlabels = np.array(['t1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5'])
xpos = np.arange(xlabels.shape[0])
ylabels = np.array(['ts1', 'ts2'])
ypos = np.arange(ylabels.shape[0])

xposM, yposM = np.meshgrid(xpos, ypos, copy=False)

zpos = result
zpos = zpos.ravel()

dx = 0.2
dy = 0.2
dz = zpos
ax1.w_xaxis.set_ticks(xpos + dx / 2.)
ax1.w_xaxis.set_ticklabels(xlabels)
ax1.w_yaxis.set_ticks(ypos + dy / 2.)
ax1.w_yaxis.set_ticklabels(ylabels)
values = np.linspace(0.2, 1., xposM.ravel().shape[0])

#create a subplot
dx = 0.2
dy = 0.2
dz2 = weight

# Set z position to the values of the first histogram
zpos2 = dz

ax1.bar3d(xpos, ypos, zpos, dx, dy, dz, color='lightcyan', zsort='average', alpha=0.7)
ax1.bar3d(xpos, ypos, zpos2, dx, dy, dz2, color='turquoise', zsort='average', alpha=0.7)

plt.show()
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\k\PycharmProjects\app\Location_Decision_Framework.py", line 41, in 
ax1.bar3d(xpos, ypos, zpos, dx, dy, dz, color='lightcyan', zsort='average', alpha=0.7)
File "C:\Users\k\PycharmProjects\app\venv\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\mplot3d\axes3d.py", line 2541, in bar3d
x, y, z, dx, dy, dz = np.broadcast_arrays(
File "<**array_function** internals>", line 5, in broadcast_arrays
File "C:\Users\k\PycharmProjects\app\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\stride_tricks.py", line 538, in broadcast_arrays
shape = _broadcast_shape(*args)
File "C:\Users\k\PycharmProjects\app\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\stride_tricks.py", line 420, in _broadcast_shape
b = np.broadcast(*args[:32])
ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape

Comment: The obvious answer to your question is, and this is what the error message tells you,  that you try to use arrays of different lengths when creating the graph. The parameters for [`bar3d`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.html?highlight=bar3d#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.bar3d) can be either an array or a float (that internally will be converted to an array of the appropriate length). However, you cannot supply arrays of different lengths - in your case, x has 5 values, y 2, and z 10.

Comment: I assume you think that matplotlib can guess how to repeat x and y for the 10 z-values but the mapping is ambiguous. Therefore, neither matplotlib nor I can provide a solution with certainty how your final graph should look like. You should describe how the data in results and weight should be represented in your graph. Or maybe you will now be able to solve your problem based on these hints.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer already! Is there a way in which I can repeat my x value so that it fits with the z= 10?

Comment: Numpy has two main commands: [`np.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) repeating each element of an array and [`np.tile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html#numpy.tile) repeating the array. You will easily find out how to combine them in your case to have the desired x-y combinations of your arrays.

Comment: `np.tile` worked! Many thanks! Based on your tile insight I was also able to find this stackoverflow: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45969974/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-plot-3d-array-in-python) for those with a similar problem!

Comment: Glad to hear this. Good luck with your project.